# Best practices for model validation using a REST API and a javascript front-end such as Angular

Tags: angularjs, validation, rest

I'm transitioning towards more responsive front-end web apps and I have a question about model validation. Here's the set-up: the server has a standard REST API for inserting, updating, retrieving, etc. This could be written in Node or Java Spring, it doesn't matter. The front-end is written with something like Angular (or similar).

What I need is to figure out where to put the validation code. Here's the requirements:

- All validation code should be written in one place only. Not both client and server. this implies that it should reside on the server, inside the REST API when persisting.
- The front-end should be capable of understanding validation errors from the server and associating them to the particular field that caused the error. So if the field "username" is mandatory, the client can place an error next to that field saying "Username is mandatory".
- It should be possible to validate correct variable types. So if we were expecting a number or a date and got a string instead, the error would be something like "'Yo' is not a correct date."
- The error messages should be localized to the user's language.

Can anyone help me out? I need something simple and robust.

Thanks

Comment: what is the reasoning behind having validation only on the server, the great advantage of having a frame work like angular or backbone is that you can easily validate on the front end before passing the data to your server

Comment: @Quince: you should have validation on the backend anyway if it's exposed to make sure that you're prepared for malicious input as well. In case you have the validation at one place however it becomes a burden to maintain the same logic in two different places.

Comment: Oh yeah I was just wondering why only on server. I use the front end to make sure individual items can pass validation then backend if anything fails I send one error to say the request was unsuccessful in general but if they have passed all my front end validation there is either server problem in which case I show an error or they have tampered with the request in which case I don't care they don't know of what specific item of the request failed

Comment: @Quince: exactly what fejese said. Writing the same validation code twice just sucks, and you always need to have them exactly aligned. So obviously the validation should reside on the server to prevent malicious input.

Comment: Think from a UX perspective ... faster to have validation on client. Think from a security perspecive ... need to have validation on server. Answer ... you need both. Question ... is there a framework that lets you write the code once and compiles it to both client and server sides?

Comment: agree it sucks to have to write it twice but IMO i want to stop bothering the server in the 99% of cases where the user has typed something wrong.

Comment: I agree that bothering the server is not ideal, but since we are posting small JSON requests only after the form is filled out I think the UX experience won't suffer too much.

Comment: @Ruskin: I remember reading some solution using Node.js and another javascript framework that allowed you to write validation code just once and have it run both on the server and the client. If only I can remember what it was...

Comment: @Ruskin: I found the solution. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research I found a solution using the Meteor.js platform. Since it's a pure javascript solution running on both the server and the client, you can define scripts once and have them run on both the client and the server.

From the official Meteor documentation:

> Files outside the **client**, **server** and **tests** subdirectories are loaded on both the client and the server! That's the place for model definitions and other functions.

Wow. Defining models **and** validation scripts only once is pretty darn cool if you ask me. Also, there's no need to map between JSON and whatever server-side technology. Plus, no ORM mapping to get it in the DB. Nice!

Again, from the docs:

> In Meteor, the client and server share the same database API. The same exact application code — like validators and computed properties — can often run in both places. But while code running on the server has direct access to the database, code running on the client does not. This distinction is the basis for Meteor's data security model.

Sounds good to me. Here's the last little gem:

> **Input validation:** Meteor allows your methods and publish functions to take arguments of any JSON type. (In fact, Meteor's wire protocol supports EJSON, an extension of JSON which also supports other common types like dates and binary buffers.) JavaScript's dynamic typing means you don't need to declare precise types of every variable in your app, but it's usually helpful to ensure that the arguments that clients are passing to your methods and publish functions are of the type that you expect.

Anyway, sounds like I've found the a solution to the problem. If anyone else knows of a way to define validation once and have it run on both client and server please post an answer below, I'd love to hear it.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

When validating your input and it fails you can return a response in appropriate format (guessing you use `JSON`) to contain the error messages along with a proper HTTP error code.

Just working on a project with a `Symfony` backend, using `FOSRestBundle` to provide proper REST API. Using the form component of `Symfony` whenever there's a problem with the input a well structured `JSON` response is generated with error messages mapped to the fields or the top level if for example there's unexpected input.

Comment: This is an interesting approach. Just return the same JSON object that was sent to the server with additional error fields on each property or top level if generic. There's just two problems: I need to use the Symfony backend (which I don't know) and the client side needs to be extended to understand these errors. But still, a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

To be strict, your last gate keeper of validation for any CRUD operations is of course on server-side. I do not know what is your concern that you should handle your validation on one end only(either server or client), but usually doing on ***both sides*** is better for both user experience and performance.

Say your `username` field is a mandatory field. This field can be easily handled in front-end side; before a user click `submit` and then been sent to the server and then get returned and shows the error code. **You can save that round trip with a one liner code in front-end**.

Of course, one may argue that from client-side the bad guys may manipulate the data and thus bypassing the front-end validation. That goes to my first point - your final gate keeper in validation should be on your server-side. That's why, data integrity is still the server's job. Make sure whatever that goes into your database is clean, dry and valid.

To answer you question, (biased opinion though) AngularJS is still a pretty awesome framework to let you do front-end validation, as well as providing a good way to do server-side error handling.

Comment: Yes, I agree with everything you said, and obviously that's the way we all work, but I still wish I only had to write it once. There's got to be a way.